# Is QString safe about buffer overflow?

Tags: c++, qt

As far as I know, the Qt documentation for [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html) does not talk about this subject.
Anyone could elaborate on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QString` dynamically allocates memory for the data you want it to contain, so no overflow can happen.

Although you still have a chance to crash you program if you try to access the string data outside of its bounds using `QString::at(int position)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the wrong question: No library code is safe from buffer overflows. You can abuse any data structure in any way you want. When you use the library code correctly, and assuming it has no bugs, then sure, you'll be safe from buffer overflows. But so you will be when you write every very low level C code correctly, as well.

The right question to ask is: Can `QString` or other C++ container classes be used to help **you** avoid buffer overflows due to silly mistakes? Yes. But, ultimately, it's on *you* to understand how buffer overflows happen, and to audit your code accordingly, no matter what libraries you use.